# Redirect Domain and Slug to different Domain with using same Slug

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, nginx

I'm not sure how to word this in simple form to return the appropriate search results, so I've created a Stack.

I have two domains.

**Domain1.com**

**Domain2.com**

I want all instances of **Domain2.com** to redirect to **Domain1.com** automatically.

If a slug path is provided for **Domain2.com** I want that slug path carried over to be detected by **Domain1.com**.

Then, I want **Domain1.com** to detect anything coming from **Domain2.com** and to redirect accordingly to the matching slug path on **Domain1.com**.

Example:

***Domain2.com/this-slug***

automatically redirects to

***Domain1.com/this-slug***

... because **Domain1.com** understands what to do exactly with **Domain2.com** and **any slug** if passed along with it.

I would prefer (I think) this to be done via .htaccess but I am open to other methods. In the next year I expect to move to NGINX so I'm not sure how that would work which is why I'm open to other methods to carry over at that time.

I think the difference from search results I did find is that I want this done automatically and not to enter manually the slug path for each one needed. I'm essentially using **Domain2.com** as Share URL to **Domain1.com**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to redirect **domain2.com/this-slug** to **domain1.com/this-slug**, add these rewrite rules to domain2.com's htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# First condition, requested resource is not an existing file in domain2.com (this condition can be removed if needed)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Second condition, requested resource is not an existing directory file in domain2.com (this condition can be removed if needed)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Third condition, slug must exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$

# Do the redirection
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain1.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Please note that with this rewrite rule **domain2.com/something/this-slug** *would redirect* to **domain1.com/something/this-slug**, if you don't want to redirect if there are intermediate slashes within the request URI, use this as third condition instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?[^/]+$
```

Comment: Awesome bro! Appreciate it! Question, do you know of the wording or a resource or know how I can use Google Analytics before the redirect? So I can at least see which visits are redirecting to Domain1.com? Or maybe I should be going about it an entirely different way?

Comment: Place your google analytics code in domain1.com then you'll be able to track the redirected traffic by filtering by *http referrer* = domain2.com

Comment: @EduardoEscobar greatly appreciate if you can help us with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66022215/domain-mapping-setup-for-slug-of-a-different-domain